# Xcode build error 'InputFile' should have exactly five arguments

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6.2 (6C131e) to build my cocoa project. It was working very smoothly but today i got following error:

```
2015-06-01 11:53:59.911 xcodebuild[2060:184936] error: InputFile    /Users/parag/workspace/myapp for Mac/Mac/HelperTool-Prefix.pch 0 1429610467 187 33188... malformed line 9; 'InputFile' should have exactly five arguments
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `SharedPrecompiledHeaders` folder contents and `DerivedData` folder.